# Mocha/Chai issue with http get request

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

i'm having trouble with http response in chai tests, i don't know how can i get the length of the res.body unless by console.log.

it's the test i'm trying to run:

```
it('It should have a length of 3061', function(){

        chai.request('http://localhost:8080')
        .get('/api/pac/')
        .end(function(err,res){

            console.log(res.body.length); //it shows 3061
            expect(res.body).to.have.lengthOf(3061); //it causes error "Cannot read property 'body' of undefined"

        });
    });
```

if i try to do an expect with res.body, it returns "Cannot read property 'body' of undefined". But a console.log works.

A console.log(res.body) shows a json with 3061 objects. Each Object have this structure:

```
iid : {type : Number},

dnas : [{ _id : Number, 
        col : Date, 
        reproved : {type : Boolean},
        wave : {type: Number, 
                index: true}
        }],
name : { type : String,
       uppercase: true,
       index: true}
```

Comment: Can you console.log `res.body` so I can see what is you're getting the length of?

Comment: Oh, i don't have enough reputation to post images, but a console.log(res.body) returns a json with 3061 objects. like this: _[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object...]_

Comment: You dont need to take an image of anything. Just copy paste the object that is logged when you console.log(res.body) into your original question here. Please remember to use code text highlighting like you did with the rest of the code in your question.

Comment: and since there are so many objects, remove most of the objects in the body, keep the structure of it the same though.

Comment: You should also put a `done` in your `it` callback and put this in your `.end` callback (above your assertions / checks): `if (err) done(err)`; and then below your assertions / checks, put: `done()`

Comment: I'll try to do a get with less responses..

Comment: @adam your answer works here! Thanks! But why just putting this?

Comment: @LorD, I posted an answer and tried my best to explain but I'm not 100% certain why it solved your problem.

Comment: I think that put a done(); makes the test **Async** or something like this. But thanks even so.

Comment: @LorD, yes, it does, but your `chai.request().get()` is also asynchronous :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `done` to your `it` callback because `chai.request('http://localhost:8080').get()` is asynchronous. Without it, you're trying to run an assertion after `it` has finished. In other words, you need to tell `it` to wait until the HTTP get request completes. Note, I'm using some es6. Replace my arrows with callback functions if your project doesn't support es6.

```
it('should have a length of 3061', done => {
    chai.request('http://localhost:8080')
    .get('/api/pac/')
    .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) done(err);

        expect(res.body).to.have.lengthOf(3061);
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
expect(res.body.length).to.equal(3061);
```

Can remember if it's `.equal` or `.be` but one of those should work.

Comment: error persists: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Comment: This cannot fix the error reported by the OP. If the expression `res.body` in `expect()` causes "Cannot read property 'body' of undefined" (which is an error raised by the JavaScript virtual machine, not by Chai), then the expression `res.body.length` will necessarily cause the same error.

Comment: Oh you're right. I was only half looking at the error. My mistake!